# Секции в table view

Tags: ios, tableview

У меня такой вопрос: как сделать отображать секции в Table View. У меня есть словарь где клюнь это первая буква имени а значение имена которые начинаются на эту букву пример `var sectionName = [A : [Anton, Andrey], B: [Bob]]` как мне теперь отобразить это в table view?

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотри, у тебя есть функция numberOfSections, в ней ты должен вернуть количество букв

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionName.keys.count
}
```

Далее, показать тайтл на экране поможет функция:

```
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return Array(a.keys)
}
```

И все, с тайтлами закончили. В cellForRow отображаешь сами имена

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let key = Array(sectionName.keys)[indexPath.section]
        cell.textLabel.text = sectionName[key]
        return cell
}
```